# Are IO streams portable

Tags: c++, iostream, portability

I was wondering as to whether IO streams are really portable(I think they should be but want be sure) ? especially when handling files used in both unix and windows.

Specifically if I dump a double value into a file in windows and then read the same value
on unix from the file using iostreams, will it not cause problems because of variation
in the endianness of the two operating systems ?

what about formatted io ? I read somewhere, not sure where, that when it comes to manipulating formatted data, there is some difference in the way windows and unix handle the same. Can anyone please throw some light on this issue ?

Comment: If your write on one OS and read on another, you'll have problems with newline tokens. Windows uses `"\r\n"`, Linux/Unix use just `"\n"` and MacOS before OSX uses just `"\r"`, IIRC.

Comment: Endianess isn't a part of the operating system, it's part of the underlying hardware (the CPU to be more precise). So if you have an integer saved in binary form on an Apple workstation/laptop then you can read that file fine on a normal PC using Windows, Linux or FreeBSD as the CPU used is the same. The big thing to watch out for is line-endings (Windows uses `"\r\n"` while OSX/Linux uses `'\n'`), and path separators (Windows uses backslash \ which has to be doubled as `'\\'` while OSX/Linux uses forward slash `/`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++ standard is abstract and does not mention any particular OS (AFAIK). So, the iostream library is portable. Having said that, the C++ standard allows for certain implementation details, including some visible to the user (and not just hidden in the standard C++ library) to be implementation dependent. This allows the provider of the OS and/or compiler to choose their preferred way to implement the C++ standard.

Any code which relies on implementation-dependent behaviour is obviously not portable, not even within different versions of the same OS and/or compiler. In other words, such code should be avoided.

Note: sometimes it is necessary to write implementation-dependent code. In this case, it is essential to guard the code against breaking of the assumed implementation-dependent behaviour. For instance, a program may assume that `sizeof(long unsigned)==8`. In this case, at least a `static_assert(sizeof(long unsigned)==8,"long unsigned not 8 bytes")` should stop the compilation of invalid code, but ideally an alternative version should exist and be picked instead via template magic (or C-style macros). The C++11 standard actually provides the type `std::uint64_t` with *guaranteed* `sizeof(std::uint64_t)==8` (and similar) to avoid such issues. However, `sizeof(ostream)` remains implementation dependent.

Answer (score 1):

File input output : Yes they are compatable. A bit stream in Unix is same as a bit stream on windows. A double value in Unix is same as that of Windows as both follow the [standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Formatting: I am not aware of any binary formatting (in the example of double) and you may be talking about text. Text formatting in windows is different from Unix and this is the cause of many problems.

Binary Interface / Code portability : If you are using  functions for IO, then it is not portable. std::input/output streams, i.e., f/o/stream implementation is not portable and neither was it designed to be portable.

Comment: All good, but there is no more STL. It is a Standard C++ Library these days. STL is a template library from SGI. Also, there are no bit streams as CPUs generally cannot address bits, the smallest addressable thing is a byte (octet), which is 8 bit. For example, you cannot create a file of size equal to 7 bit.

Comment: @Vlad : Yes, it is now part of the standard.
Agreed on the byte(octet) as the least count. Have got so used to referring to them as bit streams.

Comment: Well, it is not. It has influenced it a lot, but it is not a part of the standard.

Comment: @Vlad : Then what about std::thread ? Is it not a part of C++11 ?

Comment: @Ram you should avoid referring to out-dated things such as *STL*, but rather refer to the (which?) standard. Also, it's not clear as to why the C++ standard is not portable. It is not linked to any operating system, so should be portable.

Comment: @Walter:Agreed on STL. Example code: std::ofstream myfile; If I create this instance and pass it into or out of the library then because the size of std::ofstream is implementation dependent, it will not be portable. How do I put this across.

Comment: @Ram Okay. the standard allows for certain things to be implementation dependent. These things are obviously not portable and any code that relies on implementation-dependent behaviour not only is non-portable, but also may break (including undefined behaviour) with any future releases of compiler/OS ... In other words, such code is dangerous.

Comment: @Ram:  So are you saying that the Standard Library does not have a defined, portable binary interface?

Comment: @John : exactly what I should have said 10 mins ago. Thank you. Due to the missing standard for a binary interface, implementation dependency creeps in.

Comment: @Ram:  If you could update your answer to be be more specific, I'll upvote it.  As it is, "The STL is not portable" is wrong if we don't know that you're referring to *binary* portability.

Answer (score 1):

It's portable to the extent that if you write a particular sequence of bytes from one system, transfer that sequence to another system (by file or by socket, it doesn't really matter), you can read back the same sequence of bytes on the other side. If you write or read in text mode rather than binary mode, then line-endings (and I think in theory other implementation-defined special characters) might be re-interpreted.

What *isn't* portable is the precise representation of `double` as a sequence of bytes, either binary *or* formatted. Binary because of for example endian-ness, and formatted because of subtle differences in the runtime libraries that might mean your results can be a ulp (or sometimes more) different when encoding to string by one system and back to `double` by another, even if you output what should be enough decimal digits of precision. The string representation of NaN values is also left to the implementation.

As far as the C++ standard is concerned, `double` isn't required to be an IEEE double precision value. So there could in theory be nothing in common between the binary representations, and also big differences in terms of which values can be represented and hence which strings are output/accepted when doing formatted I/O. In practice, IEEE is commonly used and strings usually don't introduce any more error than you'd expect in floating-point operations.

Comment: So endian-ness does come into picture for double values when used across platforms ? So basically you mean to say that standard lib doesn't manage endian-ness and we have to deal it ourselves if we are building portable applications ?

Comment: @Arun: it comes into play if you do something like `stream.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&mydouble), sizeof(mydouble))`. There's no way the standard library could possibly endian-ness for that -- all it knows is that you've told it to write 8 bytes, so it does what you told it to. Standard streams have a bit of formatting built in but are not a general-purpose serialization library. Such libraries are available for C++ (e.g. Boost.Serialize, Google protocol buffers), but are not standard.